# Multiple java version usage in pipeline jobs

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline, devops

We have upgraded the ant jar files to 51 which needs to detect the java version11 but our old applications are still using the old jar file50 so we need to detect the java versions according to the pull request id. here we give PR id as parameter.

```
stage("abc"){
        steps{ 
        script{
      if (PR_ID == '100')
      tools{
        jdk 'java11.0.5'
      }
      else
    tools{
        jdk 'java8'
    fi
      }
```

i am trying this way but getting error like java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'tools' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, addInteractivePromotion, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryEditProps.

Kindly help me on how can we use if else condition or any other condition to detect the java version according to the PR id.

Answer (score 0):

A `tools` block is only allowed inside a `pipeline` block or `stage` block, not inside a `script` block.

What I would suggest is creating two different stages and using `when` to select the one to execute.

```
stage("abc-java11") {
  when {
    expression {
      return PR_ID == '100'
    }
  }
  
  tools {
    jdk 'java11.0.5'
  }

  steps {
    // Your steps
  }
}

stage("abc-java8") {
  when {
    expression {
      return PR_ID != '100'
    }
  }
 
  tools {
    jdk 'java8'
  }

  steps {
    // Your steps
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steenbeeke, it's working fine. but we have many stages. is it possible to keep it in anywhere of the pipelines or outside of the pipeline and apply to all of our stages?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how your projects are organized. I would recommend creating two separate scripts, one for each tool version, and then at the job config level specify which of the two you want to use. Better yet: if each project has its own repo, then just have each project specify their own Jenkinsfile and add it to the project root